# Подписки инстаграм

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мб у кого то ест функция на python для подписки и отпики от одного пользователя в инстаграмм?
Пошарил на гитхабе, нашел пару программ типа https://github.com/instabot-py/instabot.py

у него в ридми написано вот что на счет этого

Follow:

bot.follow('user_id')

Unfollow:

bot.unfollow('user_id')
For example (follow and unfollow user with id 111111111):

bot.follow(111111111)
bot.unfollow(111111111)

Но я просмотрел код и ничего связанного с этим не нашел.
Мб кто то знает примеры таких программ, помогите плиз

Comment: вместо "есть ли готовая программа", более полезный вопрос был бы "как сделать конкретную  вещь X" и подробно описать требования в вашем конкретном случае. Чем конкретно вас follow/unfollow не устраивают, что вы ожидали получить (детально), что вместо этого происходит?

Comment: @jfs там не указано где их вызывать. Если логично то в example.py но я там их вызывал разными способами, это повлекло за собой только ошибку программы.
Ну и как сделать подписку и отписку на питоне было бы неплохо узнать ибо я не нашел ни одного примера на гите по поиску и в гугле тоже

Comment: в комментарии не помещайте информацию необходимую для ответа, отредактируйте ваш вопрос вместо этого (есть кнопка [edit]). *"ни одного примера"* -- а что по вашему `bot.follow(111111111) ` делает?

Comment: @jfs ни одного примера работающих программ. Эта строка всего лишь функцию вызывает, а сама функция не написана, я не нашел ее, пробовал вставлять этот код в разные позы этой программы, всегда была ошибка. Вот и попросил помощь тут

Comment: ожидать чтобы программа делала именно то что нужно может пользователь, а не программист. Программист обязан хотя бы из готовых кубиков собирать (на уровне Лего). К примеру, если вы не можете самостоятельно пример написать полный скрипт с bot.follow(id), то можете спросить "а как bot получить?" (наверняка в репозитории пример есть — посмотрите в example.py) Не говорите, "что обыскал и не нашёл" когда речь идёт о распространённой задаче — это плохо звучит; лучше скажите "попробовал это и то, получил вот это, в нужно вот это"